# Does an Integral of a Function Diverge if the Function Diverges at a Single Point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $\|\cdot \|$ be the usual Euclidean Norm.

Let the differentiable functions $\{g_k(t)\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and defined on $[0,T]$, be such that there exists a points $c_k\in[0,T]$ such that $\|g_k(c_k)\| \to \infty$.  Then can we conclude that

$$ \int_0^T \|g_k(s)\|ds\underset{k\to \infty}{\to} \infty~~?  $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take $n=1$. We can construct a  differentiable function (in fact a  $C^{\infty}$ function) $g$ such that $g(\frac 1 k) =k, 0 \leq g\leq k$ on $(\frac  1 k -\frac 1 {k^{3}},\frac  1 k +\frac 1 {k^{3}})$ and $g(x)=0$  if $x \notin \bigcup_j (\frac  1 j -\frac 1 {j^{3}},\frac  1 j +\frac 1 {j^{3}})$. In this case $\int |g(s)|ds $ is finite but $g(\frac 1 k) \to \infty$. Now take $g_k=g$ for all $k$.